# How can omit Null values in columns and shift/replace omited values by right values (shift columns to left) in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have table in SQL 2016 like this.

```
T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6
----------------------
A   B   C       5   E
    F           6
                0   H
I       J   K   0    L
        M   N   1
P               0
Q   R   S   T   7   V
```

The result must be as following by omitting NULL values and shift cell values from right to left. I do this by "case when" hardly. Is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Result must be:

```
T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6
----------------------
A   B   C   5   E
F   6
H                    
I   J   K   L
M   N   1
P
Q   R   S   T   7   V
```

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable1](
[T1] [nvarchar](50) NULL, [T2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[T3] [nvarchar](50) NULL, [T4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[T5] [int] NULL, [T6] [nvarchar](50) NULL)

GO
insert into [MyTable1] (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6) values ('A','B','C','',5,'E');
insert into [MyTable1] (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6) values ('','F','','',6,'');
insert into [MyTable1] (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6) values ('','','','','','H');
insert into [MyTable1] (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6) values ('I','','J','K','','L');
insert into [MyTable1] (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6) values ('','','M','N',1,'');
insert into [MyTable1] (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6) values ('P','','','','','');
insert into [MyTable1] (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6) values ('Q','R','S','T',7,'V');
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. Its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, you are in luck because a lateral join is just what you need:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as t1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as t2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as t3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then col end) as t4,
             max(case when seqnum = 5 then col end) as t5,
             max(case when seqnum = 6 then col end) as t6             
      from (select col, row_number() over (order by ind) as seqnum
            from (values (1, T1), (2, T2), (3, T3), (4, T4), (5, T5), (6, T6)
                 ) v(ind, col)
            where col <> ''
           ) v
     ) v;
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for your attention. Data type for my fields are different. one filed int another nvarchar and etc. When I checked your code, it seems that code works only for columns with same data type. therefore i changed my question by changing datatype for field T5 to INT. Please check it again. Tanks again.

Comment: @R.Salehi . . . Your question doesn't make sense if the values are of different types, because you cannot represent a string in an integer column.

Comment: Can we cast data type to achieve that?

Comment: @R.Salehi . . . You could do that, but it really doesn't make sense to move data into a column of a different type.